# Very complex post query

Tags: posts, query, tax-query, date-query

I need to create a very complex post query, but I don't know if such a query can exist, or if I have to write PHP code to combine the results of two different queries...

Let me please describe the situation first, and then write what I've done so far.

So, I need to return results from a CPT. The CPT has its own taxonomy, where I've inserted the necessary terms. The terms have to do with different genre of the CPT itself. There is a specific term, that I don't want results from, there is the majority of the terms that I want to retrieve the results of a given date, and there are 3 specific terms, that I want results from the last 5 days of that same given date.

If that was the case, I'd simply write two different queries, and merge the results in a single array for display.

The problem is that ALL returned posts (the ones of that given date, and those from the last 5 days) need to be sorted by a custom field. In my individual queries I took that sorting into consideration using the appropriate orderby arguements, but when combined, the total sorting is gone, because I get the results of the first query sorted alone, and then the results of the second query sorted alone; where I need them to be sorted combined. So let me write the code of the queries...

This is the first excluding the 4 specific terms:

```
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'frontpage_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date('Y', $date),
            'month' => date('m', $date),
            'day' => date('d', $date),
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'newspaper_genre',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(
                7670,
                7674,
                7684,
                7686,
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And the second that includes only the 3 specific terms:

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'frontpage_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year' => date('Y', $date_minus_five),
                'month' => date('m', $date_minus_five),
                'day' => date('d', $date_minus_five),
            ),
            'before' => array(
                'year' => date('Y', $date),
                'month' => date('m', $date),
                'day' => date('d', $date),
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'newspaper_genre',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(
                7674,
                7684,
                7686,
            ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

So, the question is, am I missing a query setup where I can somehow combine specific date_query params with speecific tax_query params, and also other date_query params with other tax_query params and all these in a single query?

Or do I have to merge, the two retrieved resultsets, and then redo the sorting programmatically?

TIA

Comment: did you try nesting your two tax queries exactly how you nested your date_query?  It should work fine.

Comment: It shouldn't, and wouldn't, work because each different term corresponds to different days. So it's not a matter of nesting 2-3 different tax_query setups because in that case all of them would share the same period of time (a.k.a date_query). The approach is different, and for the sake of completeness I'll share it as an answer later today!

Comment: good luck to you Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got inspired in solving my problem by [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135820/merge-2-args-in-one-wp-query-and-order-it-by-date) thread!

The idea is to create individual queries (unordered to save time, as sorting is not needed at this stage) to get the post IDs that meet your criteria; then take those IDs and run a final query with the IDs as the criteria to get the full posts (ordered and everything at this stage). Such a code would look like this:

```
$ids1 = get_posts(array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date('Y', $date),
            'month' => date('m', $date),
            'day' => date('d', $date),
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'newspaper_genre',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(
                7670,
                7674,
                7682,
                7684,
                7686,
                8099,
                8101,
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
));

$ids2 = get_posts(array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date('Y', $date),
            'month' => date('m', $date),
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'newspaper_genre',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(
                7682,
                8099,
                8101,
            ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
));

$ids3 = get_posts(array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year' => date('Y', $date_minus_five),
                'month' => date('m', $date_minus_five),
                'day' => date('d', $date_minus_five),
            ),
            'before' => array(
                'year' => date('Y', $date),
                'month' => date('m', $date),
                'day' => date('d', $date),
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'newspaper_genre',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(
                7674,
                7684,
                7686,
            ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
));

$query = get_posts(array(
    'include' => array_merge($ids1, $ids2, $ids3),
    'post_type' => 'frontpage',
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        'date' => 'ASC',
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'frontpage_order',
));
```